# is it possible to disable implicit ToString() call?

Tags: c#

I'm wondering if there is a way to get a compilation error for this code:

```
var customer = new SomeCustomerClass();
Console.WriteLine("Customer address:" + customer);
```

so I will be forced to write something like this:

```
var customer = new SomeCustomerClass();
Console.WriteLine("Customer address:" + customer.FormatAddress());
Console.WriteLine("Customer accounts:" + customer.FormatAccounts());
```

If "ToString" would be an interface, I could do that using explicit interface implementation in my class.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think so, but you can override `.ToString()` in your customer object and provide your own implementation.

Comment: I get what you're asking, but why do you need it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no way to prevent this code at compile time.  `Object.ToString` is a part of the public contract of every object and there are no ways to prevent it from being invoked at compile time.  In this particular case the compiler will resolve the `+` to `String.Concat(object, object)` and the implementation ends up invoking `Object.ToString`.  There is no way to change this.  I think your smoothest path forward is to override `ToString` and have it call into `FormatAddress`

Please do not change `ToString` to throw an exception as a few others are suggesting.  The majority of .Net expects that `ToString` exists and is non-throwing.  Changing that will have many unexpected negative side effects to your program (including killing the debug experience for those objects)

Comment: of course i would override if I only need a different name :) A customer has multiple (and I mean it - A LOT) "information" fields which needs to be printed, and missing ".FormatXXX" is kinda hard to notice for developers, then it goes to business and sometimes they miss it too... Thanks for the answer, anyway. I was 99% sure it can't be done but wanted to get a second opinion.

Comment: Is this what you really want? Tostring is meant for debugging purposes. I get the feeling that tostring is 'abused' to get the object represent itself in something to meet a requirement. If thats the case I wouldnt do this tbh

Comment: You might want to change your `FormatX` methods to `ToXString` or `ToString(X)` (where `X` refers to a type like `enum X { Address, Accounts }`: an enum of the things you might print), to help developers find the proper methods more intuitively (these conventions are used in built-in types such as `DateTime` and `double` to format in certain ways).

Comment: @bas `ToString` is used for debugging but also used in many other places (in particular formatting)

Comment: Just to clarify: the C# compiler will codegen the addition operator as a call to `String.Concat(object, object)`; it is the `Concat` method that calls `ToString` on its parameters.

Comment: @bas - the problem is not that I want to use ToString() or I want to use default behavior. The problem is that developers forget to press "." after customer class in long concatenation clauses - and instead of printing customer information, type name is printed. And there is no way to check this except going through all business logic and reading it carefully. Hope that explains better my question.

Comment: @avs099 yeah it actually does :). that makes sense thx for even taking the time to clarify things. I have no choice to +1 your question then :p

Answer (score 10):

You can override ToString in your customer class and within there you can call the FormatAddress method if needed.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return FormatAddress();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mostly.

By using [this Roslyn Analyzer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ToStringWithoutOverrideAnalyzer/) as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54355115/939213) to a question of mine.

If you find it useful, please upvote the contributor of the original answer there.