# How to get an error shown when using non strings as strings (instead of an automatic use of ToString)?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

The suggested duplicate is indeed a similar question. However, the answer there covers only one option - disabling the ToString() itself. There are other possible solutions such as having Visual Studio warn me about it, or have the ToString() not be called (read the answer there carefully, he assumes it *is* called, and just explains that there is no way of "removing" ToString().), or use a lower version of C# (did it always work this way?), etc...

When I have a non string somewhere where a string is expected by the code I don't want it automatically converted to string. I want an error. For example:

```
public string Stringify()
{
    return Data + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

And `Data` is a `byte[]` I DON'T want to get:

> System.Byte[]

I want to get an error so I know I need to fix it. (There's a reason for strong typing.)

So, is there a way to get Visual-Studio/C#/.Net to show me an error/throw-an-Exception when using non strings as strings?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is it possible to disable implicit ToString() call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345517/is-it-possible-to-disable-implicit-tostring-call)

Comment: You can always write your own Roslyn Analyzer and detect implicit `.ToString()` calls on non String objects. Probably not simple solution thought..

Comment: @Thowk Thanks! Though I agree this is not a simple solution, this is the first real answer to my question. Feel free to post it as an answer. Definitely worth an upvote.

Comment: @ispiro Can you update the question a bit?  You're complaining about strong typing but you're allowing ```Data``` to be any type.  If ```Data``` is declared as a ```string``` then it will always be a ```string``` and the compiler will already complain when you abuse it.

Comment: There is already a rosyln analyzer that generates warnings when implicitly using ToString on an object that hasn't overridden ToString here https://github.com/Microsoft/Rosyln-Analyzer-ToStringWithoutOverride written by Microsoft. I don't have experience with Rosyln analyzers, so someone else could turn this into a full fledged answer.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII My question is specifically about when a variable is _not_ a string and I _mistakenly_ use it where a string is expected. Just as if you would have `int i = someString + 1` you would always get an error, so I would like to have here.

Comment: @TJRockefeller Very nice! I think Microsoft should have an option like that built into VS.

Comment: @ispiro Ok, I think I understand better now.  With that in mind I think the Roslyn Analyzer works as an answer.

Comment: @IvanFerić I wish it were so....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rosyln analyzers can be installed in your project using Nuget in Visual Studio 2017.

In particular there is a Rosyln analyzer that checks for implicit and explicit calls to `ToString()` if `ToString()` is not overridden in the class. https://www.nuget.org/packages/ToStringWithoutOverrideAnalyzer/

Installed analyzers can be found under references

[image]

By default this analyzer will produce warnings as shown by the triangle with `!`, but right clicking on the rules you can elevate any rule to be an error, or reduce it to informational.

## Potential gotcha

`Console.Write` and `Console.WriteLine` have several overloads including `Console.Write(object value)`, so if you are printing some object that hasn't overridden `ToString()` like `Console.Write(myCustomObject)` the analyzer will not catch this because there is no implicit conversion being made (at least in the code that you have written)

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly try cast Data and VS will complain if its not a string

```
public string Stringify()
{
    return (string)Data + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Comment: If I would notice it's not a string, I would fix it already. If you're suggesting I get used to doing that all the time everywhere - that would indeed help, but it's IMHO too much work.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a `string` type and use the `+` `operator` then it will call the `virtual ToString()` method for any type that isn't a `string` automatically.

You can't avoid this by just adding types to produce a `string` (at least not in a simple or practical manner).

You can do something else instead; such as

```
return (Data is string value) 
       ? value + Environment.NewLine
       : throw new Exception("Not a string"); //or return whatever else you want here.
```

If you want to make sure `Data` is always a `string` without testing then I would pass it to the method as a parameter.

```
public string Stringify(string data)
{
    return data + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

And the obvious case; if you want `Data` to be a field and always a `string` is to declare `Data` as a `string` to start with.

Edit:

As stated in comments above; I now understand that you want to basically flag any use of `virtual ToString()` calls to prevent operations like this from happening.  A comment was given to update the Roslyn Analyzer and a link to where that's already been done before.  I'm not posting those comments here to steal the answer but I do agree that, that may be the best solution for what you want.  Another option would be to use reflection but that wouldn't work until runtime.

Comment: (Not the downvoter) See my comment to the other answer please.

Comment: @ispiro Ok, so maybe I'm misunderstanding the question.  What are you wanting to happen exactly?

Comment: I want that in case I do write the offending code (because I forgot to turn `Data` into hex or whatever) to get _some_ kind of notification so that I'll know I need to fix it. Just as when I use the wrong Type anywhere else in C#.

Comment: Then I suggest always passing ```Data``` to the method as a ```string``` parameter.